# Probem Making Migrations Django

Tags: python, django

everyone. I am having a problem when trying to makemigrations.

My code is:
`start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

The error is:

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'category' to item without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is not an error, it is a prompt. It does not even have anything to do with the field you added.

Comment: Are you trying create this field 'category'? If yes, we have to set a default value.

Comment: category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2) I am creating this field.

Comment: I added a default value: category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2, default='S') but nothing changed.

Comment: You need to delete the migration which is failing and create a new one with the default. CAUTION: You need to unapply the migrations which have run after the one you want to delete otherwise it will mess up all your migrations. Also data can be lost when unapplying migrations for fields which already have data in them.